# Can someone translate this Navagraha shloka and tell me what verseform this is?

Tags: shloka, navagraha

The [Ekashloki Navagraha Stotram](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_navagraha/ekashlokInavagrahastotram.html?lang=iast) reads:

> ādhāre prathame sahasrakiraṇaṁ tārādhavaṁ svāśraye
>   māheyaṁ maṇipūrake hṛdi budhaṁ kaṇṭhe ca vācaspatim
>   bhrūmadhye bhṛgunandanaṁ dinamaṇeḥ putraṁ trikūṭasthale
>   nāḍīmarmasu rāhu-ketu-gulikānnityaṁ namāmyāyuṣe

What is the translation of this Navagraha Shloka?

Comment: Asking just the translation of particular Shloka is likely to be considered off-topic here. You should describe the issue with translation or interpretation if you have or you may ask for translation of text e.g. Stotra. But asking questions solely for the purpose of translating random verses are not encouraged. Visit [meta](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1676/277) and take a look at [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: Note that locating verse in a scripture or finding source scripture is another issue, you should ask separate question for it.

Comment: Please elobrate further your question on what you want

Comment: @Paṇḍyā You're linking to your own answer saying straight translations are off-topic. Whereas sv's answer which got almost equal votes says eve translation is on-topic and your fellow mod says they are never off-topic. Let's bring some consensus first on if it's okay or not. Your answer is only an opinion as you write in your answer. So, what should we do? close vote, reopen as we wish? I also don't understand why you linked to help center. It has nothing about translation questions.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Yes, it seems we don't have consensus for this on meta. Need more users visit and vote on meta

Comment: @Paṇḍyā It is not just votes. If we have friends and groups, we can get votes. As I commented under other meta answer, users are confused on what to vote. So, more discussion is needed and not just votes. Remember a meta post on "brigading"? We should chose based on usefulness if translations should be on-topic or not. More discussions needed on what are advantages and disadvantages on allowing those questions. Presence in "Hindu scripture" shouldn't be the only criteria. First question is "Who will translate? Will we allow based on 3 or 4 users who know Sanskrit?"

Comment: @Paṇḍyā If we see history of the site, we have closed such questions  which ask for only translation. But there seems to change in translation and you reopened or left open translation questions making changes on your own. I still don't understand why. Now you're saying they are off-topic. It's look confusing from your activity and comments.

Comment: Don't know when we  started looking for experts in specific topics to answer. Translations can be done from what is already available. No need of any Sanskrit experts. @Pandya. I am with this!

Answer (score 6):

The verse is talking about the positions of the nine planetary deities in the seven [Chakras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra) viz - Muladhara (near the anus), Swadhisthan (the Chakra near the navel), Manipura (the seat of the Fire), Anahata (heart Chakra), Vishuddha (throat Chakra), Ajna Chakra (the 3rd eye Chakra) and Sahsrara (the top of the head).

> ādhāre prathame sahasrakiraṇaṁ

[Adhara=base](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=adhara&direct=se&anz=100); [Prathama=first](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=prathama&direct=se&anz=100).So, adharae prathame= in the first base i.e. in the Muladhara. Sahasrakiraṇaṁ - Thousand-rayed= another name for Sun as noted in [Surya Kavacha Stotra by Yajnvalkya](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Surya_Kavacha_Sthothram). So, Sun is in the root Chakra or Muladhara.

> tārādhavaṁ svāśraye

Tara=Stars and [Dhavam here means Master or Lord](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=dhavam&lang=sans&action=Search). The Moon god's one name is Tarapati (lord of the stars) as noted in [the Chandra Kavacham](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Chandra_Kavacham). Swa refers to the 2nd Chakra the Swadhisthana. [Asraya=rests,depends etc](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?q=%C4%81%C5%9Braya&iencoding=iast&lang=sans). So, Moon belongs to the Swadhisthana.

> māheyaṁ maṇipūrake

Maheyam from the word [Mahi](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=mahi&direct=se&anz=100) (meaning Earth) refers to Mangala who is considered as the son of Earth. Mars is situated in the seat of Fire or in the Manipura Chakra.

> hṛdi budhaṁ kaṇṭhe ca vācaspatim

Hrudi= in the Heart, Kanthe- in the Throat

In the heart (Anahata) Budha and in the throat (kanthe) Brihaspati (Vacaspati meaning "the Lord of speech" is another name for Brihaspati).

> bhrūmadhye bhṛgunandanaṁ

Bhrumadhye=The place between the eyebrows=where the Ajna Chakra is placed. Brigunandanam=son ([nandana](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=nandana&direct=se&anz=100)) of Bhrigu referring to Shukra.

> dinamaṇeḥ putraṁ trikūṭasthale

[Dinamani is the Sun](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=dinamaNi&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3), so Dinamaneh Putra=Sun's son ([putra](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=Putra&direct=se&anz=100)) referring to Shani. [Kutastha](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=kUTastha&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) in Yoga and Tantra refers to place higher than the Ajna Chakra and near the Sahsrara. It is kind of a "Highest Place".

> nāḍīmarmasu rāhu-ketu

In the veins reside Rahu and Ketu.
I could not get the meaning of the last part but Gulika is the name of an Upa-Graha.

Regarding the location of the verse, even I don't know that like you but I want to.

Comment: Thank you very much for the translation. I found the sloka here: https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_navagraha/ekashlokInavagrahastotram.html?lang=iast

Comment: @Random-15 Can you please ask such questions in chatroom? This is comments section. Your questions are suited for more chatroom. Comments section are not for this type of discussions. Kindly cooperate!

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti sorry, I will not do such things again.

Comment: @Random-15 No need of sorry.!!!!

Comment: @Teacup Thanks for the link of the Stotram. So its about one verse and not two as I previously thought.

Comment: Can you add dictionary references for the first two blockquotes also? ('ādhāre prathame', 'sahasrakiraṇaṁ' and 'tārādhavaṁ svāśraye')

Comment: Yes, added now @sv.